# leaflet plot only coastline

Tags: leaflet

I have seen many examples on leaflet of data being plotted onto a google maps style map, is it possible to plot leaflet data onto a map with only coastline? What I'm looking for is just a white background with a black line tracing the coast, nothing else.

Comment: Are you using the javascript leaflet library or leaflet through R?

Comment: the javascript library

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could get a vector dataset of just the coastline that you are interested in... For instance, here is a worldwide coastline dataset from Natural Earth Data: https://github.com/nvkelso/natural-earth-vector/blob/master/geojson/ne_50m_coastline.geojson

You can download the raw text, and paste it in your javascript like this:

```
var coastlines = {insert geojson text here}
```

Then you can add it to your leaflet map using

```
L.geoJSON(coastlines, style = {"color": "#000"}).addTo(map);
```

Turn the background of your map white using this:

```
#map{background-color: white;}
```

https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/

You can find lots of vector data in Geojson format here: https://github.com/nvkelso/natural-earth-vector/tree/master/geojson 
including a more-detailed (10m) and a less-detailed (110m) coastline dataset.

The jsBin is too large to save, but here is a demonstration of it: [image]